# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500, in android firebase project in google sign in

Tags: android

I have given the support email in my Firebase project and my SHA-1 key has also been given, but I am still getting this issue:

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500

I tried, but I can't find a solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `Google Play Services` to the latest version. Once the emulator/device is up and running, go to the Extended Controls Menu > Google Play then update.

Answer (score 0):

For fixing this issue you have some options I don't think it's an issue with Play Services I had the same issue and this is how I fixed it was through the following way:

1. Check the SHA1 Debug key in Firebase Console if it's the same then leave it the same.
2. Go to the credential page by using  [this link](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard?)  And check for your application and if you have a web credential created for your application copy the ID and paste it in your Strings.XML file. Don't forget to change default_web_client_id with your web id most probably this will be your issue for 12500. The issue is that android credential is not working sometimes which is a reason for 12500. This hasn't been mentioned anywhere.

Comment: default_web_client_id is its generate by default this path:app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml. and my SHA1 key is correct but still getting this error.  And  Where to add or use  " web credential created for your application copy the ID and paste it in your Strings.XML"

Comment: Don't use that instead of that get the new one from Google console